# Need JQuery help in coding slider

Tags: jquery

I only can make smooth sliding of photos if i clicking slowly but if i click link fast app makes pictures jump to right without animation and even with pauses. How to solve this issue.

```
<div id="carousel">
  <a href="#" id="right"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$( "#right" ).click(function() {
  $("#carousel ul").find("li:first").before($("#carousel ul").find("li:last"));
  $("#carousel ul").css({marginLeft:-480});
  $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:0},500);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre going to want to implement a throttle. This will ensure that the user cannot rotate the carousel until after the first animation is done.

Here is an example:

```
// Global Variable
var throttleControl = false;

function functionToThrottle() {
    // Only run if not Throttling
    if( !throttleControl )

        // Turn on Throttle
        throttleControl = true;

        setTimeout(function(){ 

            /* Code to execute */

            // At end of function execution 
            // Un Throttle
            throttleControl = false
        }, /* Time of animation here */);
}
```

This will ensure that if anyone spams the click button, it will only run after the previous click event has completed.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to execute callback function of animate before it animate?

Comment: If your callback is independent of the animation, just call it before the animation. If you want to force the animation to finish on each click (which could look jittery), use the jQuery.finish() wherever you need it http://api.jquery.com/finish/.